# Is there a way to to Indent certain items in a list view using c# for a windows 8 store app?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Basically, I have a list of items and sub items (all in one list). I want to indent certain specific items that are actually sub items. Is there a function or property that I can use to do this? I've tried googling for it, and even searching for it here on stack overflow - but no success.

NOTE: I'm using C# and XAML for a windows 8 store application. Not a wpf app (the documentation and code differ sometimes).

EDIT:

Here's what my XAML looks like:

```
<ListView
            x:Name="ListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="-10,-10,0,0"
            Padding="20,0,0,45"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Item" Tag="{Binding ID}" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="40" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The listview is binded to an observablelist of objects.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @gunr2171, its just the generic code for a listview using XAML and C#. But I will update with an code example of what I have shortly

Comment: @gunr2171 I just made an edit to show some XAML code.

Comment: I just want to be able to indent specific items, these items are objects in the observable class and have an integer property for indentation.

Comment: Another option is grouping the list items depending on the UI look you want: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Expand further on another answer here... The suggested route was to add a property to the underlying class (in this case, MyClass) and bind the ItemsSource for the ListView to a list of these objects.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsSubItem { get; set; }
}

// Elsewhere in your code, you would need a list of these object
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
```

You would also need a Converter class, which is very easy to setup:
You'd need a converter class; converters are really easy once you get the hang of them. A simple example for this scenario would be:

```
public class BoolToMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //Get the passed in value and convert it to a boolean - the as keyword returns a null if we can't convert to a boolean so the ?? allows us to set a default value if we get a null instead
        bool isSubItem = (value as bool?) ?? false;
        // If the item IS a sub item, we want a larger Left Margin
        // Since the Margin Property expects a Thickness, that's what we need to return
        return new Thickness(isSubItem == true ? 24 : 12, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    // This isn't necessary in most cases, and in this case can be ignored (just required for the Interface definition)
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Once you get this setup, you'll need to add this to your XAML as a resource:

```
// Add a reference to your namespace if it isn't already in your XAML
xmlns:local="using:MyNamespace"

// You'll also need to add a static resource
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolToMarginConverter x:Key="BoolToMarginConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

// And then lastly, you'll need to update your ListView XAML to use the new information
<ListView
        x:Name="ListView"
        ItemsSource={Binding MyList}
        <!-- Other Properties removed for space -->
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="1">
                    <!-- Other info removed for space -->
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="{Binding Path=IsSubItem, Converter={StaticResource BoolToMarginConverter}}">
                        <!-- Other info removed for space -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: This is the exact type of an example I was looking for. In my project though, would I have my converter class located in a Common folder or Models folde? Since it is not a Page class

Comment: Or would the converter class be a portable class?

Comment: I usually have a few converters in my project, so I create a 'Converters' folder for them all to go in. The converter can just be a class in that folder (note that you will need to update the namespaces to also include MyNamespace.Converters for the project to be able to reference them in the XAML) using the standard Right-Click -> Add new item -> Class

Also, you'll probably need to add the following to your class:
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thank for your information, one last question though. I have added those namespaces already, system and Xaml.Data, but its not recognizing Thickness when I return new Thickness. What namespace does Thickness use?

Comment: Found it, it was Windows.UI.Xaml (without the data part)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to indent the text of the sub-items you could change the margin of the text block or stack panel.
To do this you would do the following:

1. Create a class for the items you will be adding to the list view
2. Add to the class, an IsSubItem property
3. Create an observable collection of these items and bind them to your list view source.
4. In the ListView template, bind the stack panel or text block margin to the IsSubItem property using a converter to convert the IsSubItem boolean into the appropriate margin.

Comment: I have an observablelist of classes that have an indent property. So I guess at this point I would only need to implement the converter. For reference only, could you possible make generic code on how to implement the converter? Thanks.

Comment: Also, would I have to make a converter class ? Or can I just set the margin binding to a private function within the page class definition?

Comment: I just saw your additional questions - I am happy to see someone has already answered them - looks like you are on your way.